# How to call the method of the pointer type(disabling polymorphism)?

Tags: c++

I got two classes:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int get() {
    return 1;
  }
};

 class Bar : public Foo {
  public:
   int get() override {
     return 2;
   }
 };
```

and now I got a pointer which points to a `Bar` object:

```
Foo* foo = new Bar;
```

now I want to call the `get()` which belongs to type `Foo` though pointer `foo`, as if the `get()` is not virtual, any way to do this?

Comment: Try: `foo->Foo::get();` But, what is your use-case? The code is polymorphic but you're disabling it, why is that?

Comment: why is `get` virtual when you want it non-virtual?

Comment: @Azeem just curious, not in real usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `foo->Foo::get();`

I hope that it won't be in the production code though. :)

Comment: Note that it doesn't disable polymorphism: if `Foo::get` calls `virtual void Foo::bar()`, that one would be called polymorphically.

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks! Noted. Maybe, the OP uses a compiler flag e.g. GCC's `fno-rtti` but it's not been stated.